# What do I put in the form action attr on top of form wordpress

Tags: actions, forms

I created an html form, but have no clue, what I must put in the <form action = on top of the form. Does the user info go to the database, or to a file in wordpress. I am not sure what to put there. At the moment, I do not have this site live. It's local by flywheel, but would just like to know. If anyone can help me here with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great article on Sitepoint that describes how to handle POST forms in WordPress:

https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Comment: Your answer must be self contained, otherwise if that URL changes or the post is deleted the answer becomes useless. Links can support an answer but they can't _be_ the answer